# How to apply a function from node package to all the files in a directory?

Tags: javascript, node.js, batch-processing, mammoth

I've installed mammoth.js module which converts docx to html. I can use it with a single file.

How do I use the same module for all the files in a specific folder? I'm trying to save an output html files while keeping the original name (not the extension, of course). Probably I have to require some other packages...
The code below is for a single file from the desired directory:

```
var mammoth = require("mammoth");

    mammoth.convertToHtml({path: "input/first.docx"}).then(function (resultObject) {
        console.log('mammoth result', resultObject.value);
      });
```

The system is win64

Comment: Read the directory with the `fs` module, it will give you a list of all files names. Then iterate over these files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')
const mammoth = require('mammoth')

fs.readdir('input/', (err, files) => {
  files.forEach(file => {
    if (path.extname(file) === '.docx') {
      // If its a docx file
      mammoth
        .convertToHtml({ path: `input/${file}` })
        .then(function(resultObject) {
          // Now get the basename of the filename
          const filename = path.basename(file)
          // Replace output/ with where you want the file
          fs.writeFile(`output/${filename}.html`, resultObject.value, function (err) {
            if (err) return console.log(err);
          });
        })
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: Works like a charm, many thanx m8! I was going to post with write into file part, but you did it faster :::-----)))

Comment: No worries! Glad it helped!